# Beveled corner on a rounded button

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I need to create a rounded button with an information badge like this one :

[image]

How can I make the beveled corner on the green button around the red information badge ?

I **cannot use a normal white border** around the red badge (like in the below snippet), **because it must be transparent** and displays the page background color.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(0, 199, 158);
  margin: 25px;
}
.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid white;
  background: rgb(255, 67, 0);
}
body {
  background: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'></div>
```

Comment: I have added a dummy code into the question (the one with white border) because questions without code tend to get closed (even though it is not mandatory for code to be present in question). This was an attempt to prevent closure of an otherwise good question. Please feel free to rollback if you aren't fine with my edits :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using Box Shadow:**

One approach would be to use `box-shadow` on a pseudo-element like in the below snippet. Here, one pseudo-element (`.shape:before`) is positioned in such a way that it is a bit above the top-right corner of the circle and then its box shadow is used to fill the parent (`.container`) with required background color. The badge is added via another pseudo-element on the `.container` element.

This has better browser support than the `radial-gradient` approach as it works in IE8+. Drawbacks would be that it can only support a solid background color for the main circle as shadows cannot be a gradient or an image. Also, it seems to require two elements (*I am trying to reduce it and if successful will add it into answer*).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px;
}
.shape {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 60%;
  width: 60%;
  top: -20%;
  right: -20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 50px rgb(0, 199, 158);
}
.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '2';
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  right: -20%;
  top: -20%;
  background: rgb(255, 67, 0);
  color: white;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* just for demo */

*, *:after, *:before {
  transition: all 2s;
}
.container:hover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.container:hover .shape:before {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px rgb(0, 199, 158);  
}
.container:hover:after {
  line-height: 50px;
}
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='shape'></div>
</div>
```

---

**Using Radial Gradient:**

Another option would be to use `radial-gradient` for `background-image` like in the below snippet and position the background such that it produces a beveled corner on the top right. Once its done, adding the badge circle and positioning it should be fairly straight-forward.

This has poorer browser support compared to the `box-shadow` approach as it works only in IE10+. If responsiveness is required then using gradients would be a better option as they can take percentage values unlike box shadows.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(60% 60% at 92.5% 7.5%, transparent 49.5%, rgb(0,199,158) 50.5%);
  margin: 25px;
}
.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '2';
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  right: -20%;
  top: -20%;
  background: rgb(255,67,0);
  color: white;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* just for demo */

*, *:after {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.shape:hover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.shape:hover:after {
  line-height: 50px;
}
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'></div>
```

---

**Using SVG:**

Another possibility would be to make use of SVG to create the beveled circle like in the below snippet.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
svg path {
  fill: rgb(0, 199, 158);
}
.shape:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '2';
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  right: -25%;
  top: -5%;
  background: rgb(255, 67, 0);
  color: white;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* just for demo */

*, *:after {
  transition: all 2s;
}
.shape:hover {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.shape:hover:after {
  line-height: 50px;
}
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 60 60'>
    <path d='M55,30 A25,25 0 0,1 5,30 A25,25 0 0,1 42.5,8.34 A16,16 0 0,0 55,30' />
  </svg>
</div>
```

> **Note:** I've used pseudo-element for the badge just for illustration but since you'd need to add dynamic content into it, I'd recommend replacing that with a child element.